# A question seeking for factual answer wrongly closed as "Off-topic/MCVE"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

Refer to this question: [How many digits of the double type can survive when going from C# to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51722183/3834)

It was closed for the reason "Off-topic":

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
>   must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example." – Hans Passant, Alan Birtles, Narendra Jadhav, mag_zbc, Rob

What?

This is ***not*** a question seeking debugging help-- in fact it is asking a factual question, and has a factual answer.

Ironically [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722183/how-many-digits-of-the-double-type-can-survive-when-going-from-c-sharp-to-c#comment90404870_51722183) actually gives the answer, and suggests a solution. So it *is* answerable, and is *not* off-topic. If the comment was posted as an answer, I would have prepared to accept it.

And I do think the question is phrased in such a way that will help incoming visitors from Google Search Engine.

**Edit 1:** I've edited the question to explicitly asked the user to not solve my code.

**Edit 2:** Someone brings up my 500+ questions history, so it is only fitting for me to elaborate on this here. If you compare my early questions vs. my lately questions, my early questions tend to receive better answers and more upvotes in general, despite that they were not necessarily better written than my current ones. I would even say that my early questions were worse-off, but the early SOers were a lot more helpful and forgiving, and tended to answer the question from an answerable angle, instead of nitpicking and finding ( very hard) an interpretation that would render the question unanswerable and *then proceed to close it as "Off topic"*.

**My question history, instead of reminds me how to write good questions, actually reminds everyone how far SO has (d)evolved in the direction of increasing unhelpfulness, hostility, nitpicking and unforgiving lately.**

Comment: Why is this question about a downvoted question downvoted? Such downvotes hardly instill any confidence in the recent [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/?cb=1) campaign.

Comment: I actually do have zero confidence in the effectiveness of the code of conduct campaign, but I'm not one of your downvoters, sorry.

Comment: On a tangential note, genuine "proper questions" getting downvotes due to disagreement (as if they were feature requests or opinionated essays) is something of an issue on Meta. Suggesting that it is in and of itself problematic to downvote questions about downvoted questions might be a step too far, though.

Comment: After I posted this question, my original question was downvoted again, any correlation between the two? I wonder sometimes

Comment: Does the CoC attempt to regulate how users vote and why?

Comment: The meta effect may not be great, but if you bring additional attention to a post, more votes may follow.  According to the perceived quality and usefulness of the post, the extra votes may go up or down. Or you believe that users shouldn’t be allowed to vote on a post because it was linked in meta?

Comment: @yivi: Some people *do* believe that, and consider that we should imitate Reddit's anti-voting-brigade code to outright bar votes on posts linked from meta and/or HNQ. I would support the latter, at any rate, and would consider the former seriously.

Comment: @Nathan I'm a bit lost, sorry. You would consider "anti-voting-brigade" seriously?

Comment: @yivi The Meta Effect is in most cases a bad thing. I feel people shouldn't downvote posts linked from Meta unless there is a clear need for outside intervention, though of course there is no real way to police that. (In line with Nathan's remarks, I would like to see Reddit-style non-participant links over here.)

Comment: @duplode I agree that piling on posts unnecessarilty is not great. Even moreso if the poster is relatively new to the network. But experienced users asking for feedback on specific posts of theirs should get it, IMO.

Comment: @Axel I do not think that votes are used to punish a user. At least I do not use them that way, and I haven't seen them used that way in the vast majority of cases where I was able to discern a reason. I believe votes are used to send a signal about content quality and usefulness. So I guess we disagree.

Comment: @yivi: Yes. The meta effect comes from [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias) and arguably a form of judgement priming. Allowing a known-biased source of considerable magnitude into the voting data is almost self-evidently bad.

Comment: @Nathan You say would be for an _"anti-voting-brigade"_, but I do not know what that is, sorry. And you argue that the meta crowd is a known-biased source, but you do not say what the bias is. I can't agreee with that statement. Still, this discussion has been absolutely derailed I guess. I'm out. Peace!

Comment: @yivi: "Voting brigade" is the Reddit term for the Meta effect. So anti-voting-brigade code is used to prevent that from working. The Meta bias is complex, but includes things like a heavy focus on site quality, impatience with sloppy users, deep interest in site mechanics, and (dis)likes of a lot of things that have become memetic on Meta that SO as a whole may not care so much about. And, of course, the obvious priming from whatever meta post had the link. Basically, MSO is its own site to some extent and has its own voting patterns accordingly, which are usually much more intense.

Comment: @Graviton, "Why is this question about a downvoted question downvoted?". Because that how meta works. Voting is different on meta. From [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), voting can indicates agreement or disagreement. Code of conduct is not "Leeloo Dalas Multipass", You should not use it every time.

Comment: I am tempted to also apply a reopen vote, just to see what good answers are forthcoming..   Unless the OP edits its question to add more details, I can't see there being any good answers:(

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the core of your question:

> #### How many digits of the double type can survive when going from C# to C++?
>
> Let's say if I pass a `double` from C# to C++, how many digits of the `double` will be preserved?

As I see it, there are two ways of interpreting it:

- As a question about the specs of the `double` types in C# and C++. Given the background context provided by the remarks about your interop code, that looks a little like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242059), but that isn't grounds for closure. Under this interpretation, "Off-topic/MCVE" wouldn't apply.
- As a question about to which extent interop code will preserve information when you "pass a `double` from C# to C++". Under this interpretation, "Off-topic/MCVE" does apply, as the answer depends specifically on what your interop code is doing.

(As an additional wording quibble, the "can survive" phrasing in the title suggests #1 , while "will be preserved" in the question body suggests #2.)

When I began to write this answer, I was strongly leaning towards #1; another look at the question, though, has made #2 feel quite reasonable. On the other hand, your remarks about Hans' comment suggest you consider #1 to be more in line with what you originally meant. Perhaps editing the question to make that clearer (e.g. by retrofitting it to better match Hans' comment) would help.

Comment: If I had voted at all, I would have gone with 'Unclear', and probably downvoted too.  The question does not make it clear how the interop is being done and misleadingly implies that doubles are stored internally as text, rather than the more usual 64/80 bit FP binary representations.  Either way, it's not a good question as it's not answerable in its original form and needs a lot of clarification:(    I won't vote on it now 'cos I don't agree with meta effects.

Comment: @MartinJames, your comment seems strange to me. Is there other than one way of commonly doing interop? I am of course referring to the most well-known ( if not the only) way of doing interop (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx)

Comment: Interop as we understand it is a pretty well-define mechanism and therefore I don't expect to link to how we do interop. If we have to redefine every single common mechanism when we are posting a SO question, then I think there is something deeply wrong with SO community; your question gets closed if it's not well-defined ( if I knew how to define a question precisely I already know how to google my way), your question gets closed if you don't explain or link to commonly known mechanism. It does seem to me like a group of users is keen on rationalizing a (wrong, IMO) collective decision.

Comment: @Graviton nobody is asking you to regurgitate the interop specification. You're asking a question about a problem with your code; then why do you not understand it could be extremely helpful to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem?That's what people are asking about, and that's why your question was closed: it contains no code to reproduce the issue. Or do you want theoretical answers (_"If you program it correctly, it will work"_)?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think we are going in circle-- my question has nothing to reproduce-- it's a factual question, looking for factual answer.

Comment: @Graviton _"my C++ library gives an incorrect output when it is receiving data from C# interop"_ - what's there not to reproduce? You even preface the question with _"Let's say if"_, making it pretty theoretical instead of factual.

Comment: @CodeCaster, that statement is meant to set the context for my question. You can just ignore it and answer the question. I don't ask you to solve the *"my C++ library gives an incorrect output when it is receiving data from C# interop"* for me ( and I don't understand how one could have interpreted it as such)

Comment: @Graviton it's very simple: if you mention in your question that you have code that's not working, people are going to expect to see that code or otherwise close-vote as non-mcve, whether that question is "factual" (whatever that means) or not. I don't really see how after 500+ questions you haven't figured that out. And even if you just want the question answered, and not your code fixed, then still, the answer would be "depends on how you pass it". Don't make potential answerers assume anything, just show a MCVE.

Comment: @CodeCaster to clear the confusion, I've edited the question to explicitly asked the user to *not* solve my code.

Comment: @CodeCaster, since you bring up my 500+ questions history, maybe let me just elaborate a bit here. If you compare my early questions vs. my lately questions, my early questions tend to receive better answers and more upvotes in general, despite that they are not necessarily better written than my current ones. This fact, instead of reminding me how to write good questions, actually reminding *everyone* how far SO has (d)evolved in the direction of increasing hostility, nitpicking and unforgiving lately.

Comment: @Graviton Saying that bad questions used to be upvoted is a problem.  Sure, it's nice for you, given that you've been able to continue asking bad questions.  But it's bad for the site.  If users are now doing a better job of accurately voting on the quality of posts, and actually trying to get people to ask good questions that actually contain the information to get good answers, that's not the site devolving.  Sure, it might be devolving from the perspective of someone who wants to ask bad questions, but it's not devolving from the perspective of people who are searching for good solutions.